# How to change color of the found character string on `projectile-find-file`?

Tags: projectile, colors

I am using `projectile-find-file` to open files.

The color of the found part of the string ex: (`bash`) in the `mini-buffer` is unreadable on my terminal. Is it possible to change its color?

Example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @NickD I forget to mention this happens in the mini-buffer. I am unable to run `customize-face` on the minibuffer to detect the color tag, facing with following error `Command attempted to use minibuffer while in minibuffer`

Comment: It does not matter where it happens: take @Viestur's answer to that question, stick it in your init file and restart emacs. Does that work?

Comment: Adding `(setq frame-background-mode 'dark)` make red into yellow. But since it is much readable , it works on my end